# The model in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

You know that in spring you can have a method that gets a model as its parameter. I am new to spring and I don't understand where does that parameter come from. Is is some kind of spring default bean or what?

Comment: In most cases, Model object is passed from either from view(eg. jsp) or any calling other method.

Comment: Oh,ok. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this article!](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/)

Generally - as always it depends on your implementation. As @Aniket Warey said Model object can be passed from view - JSP or HTML files. 
You have also something like `ModelAndView`, which works slighthy different from ordinary `Model`. You can also specify and configurate/implement your own `ViewResolver`. Spring/Spring Boot uses its own default implementation for `Model`, but like I said - you can override it.

Leaving the subject a little bit - you don't usually need to use `Model` parameter. It always depends on problem that you face, but there is for example `@RestController`, which can get/send you data as JSON. Then you can neatly manipulate it on the client/view side. There is a lot of options. :)